# Windows 10 Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 - UWP Deploy "Blocked by AppLocker"

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, applocker

Fresh install of Win 10 Anniversary Enterprise and latest VS 2015.

File => New => UWP template. Right click, Deploy. Receving the following:

```
Error       DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed. error 0xC000003A: Deployment of package f0a5d8a7-ba54-4291-bd63-068c614b1e0d_1.0.0.0_x86__0z25kj72j1pne was blocked by AppLocker. (0x80073cf9)    App1
```

Running low on ideas how to fix. Ideally I would just disable "AppLocker" but I'm not sure how.

Local Security Policy shows no rules setup. All Windows Store apps work fine.

[image]

Comment: "Fresh install" - you dis restart the PC, right?

Comment: FYI so upgrading to 10 insider 14986 (which had plans to do anyway) + VS2015 repair seems to have fixed!